# Find High Load Culprit (Apache) on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, wordpress, high-load

I have a CentOS 7 server on AWS w/ 4 CPU and 8 GB RAM. Starting late last week I started getting HIGH load spikes several times a day w/ Apache appearing to be the culprit. It's fully up-to-date w/ the latest packages.

To try and isolate, I installed Monitorix so I can see graphs of the spikes. I also started logging `uptime` every minute to try and see when the spikes happen. I noticed they all seem to be roughly every 6 hours (midnight, 6 am, noon and 6 pm).

```
18:07:02 up 1381 days, 17:55, 2 users, load average: 0.51, 0.67, 1.13
18:08:04 up 1381 days, 17:56, 2 users, load average: 6.86, 2.01, 1.54
18:09:30 up 1381 days, 17:57, 2 users, load average: 101.18, 32.53, 12.26
18:10:02 up 1381 days, 17:58, 2 users, load average: 80.26, 34.50, 13.59
18:11:01 up 1381 days, 17:59, 2 users, load average: 30.24, 28.51, 12.84
18:12:01 up 1381 days, 18:00, 2 users, load average: 11.99, 23.59, 12.13
18:13:01 up 1381 days, 18:01, 2 users, load average: 5.26, 19.50, 11.44
18:14:01 up 1381 days, 18:02, 2 users, load average: 2.14, 16.03, 10.75
...
00:57:01 up 1382 days, 45 min, 2 users, load average: 0.28, 0.39, 0.50
00:58:04 up 1382 days, 46 min, 2 users, load average: 11.42, 2.85, 1.30
00:59:01 up 1382 days, 47 min, 2 users, load average: 4.90, 2.49, 1.26
01:00:01 up 1382 days, 48 min, 2 users, load average: 1.80, 2.04, 1.18
...
12:42:01 up 1382 days, 12:30, 2 users, load average: 0.20, 0.47, 0.56
12:43:09 up 1382 days, 12:31, 2 users, load average: 35.63, 8.82, 3.32
12:44:02 up 1382 days, 12:32, 2 users, load average: 48.94, 18.08, 6.86
12:45:02 up 1382 days, 12:33, 2 users, load average: 18.50, 14.97, 6.49
12:46:01 up 1382 days, 12:34, 2 users, load average: 8.13, 12.56, 6.19
12:47:01 up 1382 days, 12:35, 2 users, load average: 2.99, 10.27, 5.80
12:48:01 up 1382 days, 12:36, 2 users, load average: 1.14, 8.42, 5.44
```

When I look at the Monitorix images, it appears to be Apache threads causing the issue, as they spike, as well. When I can strace a PID I am seeing a ton of reads on websites (this hosts multiple Wordpress websites). There's a slight jump in memory allocation, and when I am running to pat the time, swap isn't 100% used.

I started logging MySQL slow queries and I believe what is logged is not the cause, as they're simple Wordpress SELECT statements, and all are at the time of spikes (so an effect, not the cause).

I also installed fail2ban, but that's not really logging/blocking anything.

I lastly checked all crons and nothing that I see is scheduled to run every 6 hours that would cause this.

I do see the disk I/O spikes, as well, roughly around these times (Wordfence?). Apache workers also spike at these times, as they're averaging around 10-15 until they spike to 40, 80, or 180 today alone.

What else can I look at/log? I'm 99% sure it's Apache causing the issue. All of the Wordpress sites are up-to-date, have Wordfence running (w/ scan settings set to lower usage to save resources and the blocking is set to not do all records).

TIA!

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post any Apache ini for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Wilson Hauck. I was actually able to isolate part of the problem.

Comment: Post the requested data and we can help you improve performance, please.  Welcome to Server Fault.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I appreciate the offer. But, with the age of the server, I have decided this month to switch to a managed solution to take the sysad role (if you can even call me that) off of me. Thx!

Comment: Once your managed solution is active, you may want to improve performance.  We will be here for you.  Thank You and the BEST always.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue it appears to be related to a few plug-ins that were firing when wp-cron.php ran that accessed files. These were taxing the system (Wordfence and UpDraft Plus). Changing a few settings seemed to ease the stress.